# mySQL AUTO_INCREMENT column creation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make simple database since yesterday with primary id key with AUTO_INCREMENT option but keep getting this error:

```
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `spring`.`samochod` (
`idsamochod` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idsamochod`));

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idsamochod`))' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `spring`.`samochod` (
  `idsamochod` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsamochod`))

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idsamochod`))' at line 2
```

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `spring`.`samochod` (
  `idsamochod` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsamochod`))
```

I am getting this error even for normal integer columns. I have read many articles before and as far as I understand it should work this way without any problems.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you tag mysql **and** sql-server, when your question is about MySQL?

Comment: Why do you think that this might be valid syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the AUTO_INCREMENT but the DEFAULT before it. No value has been specified for DEFAULT. Just remove the DEFAULT keyword which is not needed here.

See also the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) in the MySQL documentation, specifically:

> ```
> column_definition:
>     data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
>       [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
>       [COMMENT 'string']
>       [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
>       [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
>       [reference_definition]
> ```